# Sending HTML email with attachment with wp_mail()

Tags: wp-mail

This one should be easy, but I can't figure it out.
I want to send an email that is HTML formatted, but also has an attachment. The attachment is being sent correctly, but the message is delivered as plaintext, like this:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Best wishes,</p>
<p>Team</p>
```

If it was an email without attachment, I would force it to send html by changing the header as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). But now I need the content type to be multipart / mixed (right?). So my question is: how do I convince `wp_mail()` to send my messages as html, and include the attachment?

Comment: what is the result when you *do* set the content type to `text/html` via the provided filter? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/

Comment: You've will upon a *bug* of sort that is yet to be fixed *officially* on core. There is luckily a patch that you can add and basically you are about to step into a serious headache (*huvudvärk*) but luckily I've decreased the pain for you in my explanation on how multipart messages works with `wp_mail()` in my question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191923/sending-multipart-text-html-emails-via-wp-mail-will-likely-get-your-domain-b -- Best of luck!

Comment: @majick : it is a multipart / mixed message. It can't have content type 'text/html'.

Comment: @ChristineCooper : yeah, I read that thread, was just hoping that there is a better way to solve this by now. Urgh. :( I think I will use plaintext for content for now.

Comment: that bug should not affect you being able to do what you are asking though, see answer (and one added to the other thread identifying the cause.)

Comment: Refer this article https://www.phparticles.com/wordpress/how-to-use-wp-mail-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 4):

Reference link [click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/).

Using below code you can send the mail with html format.

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

// For attachment 

$attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";

wp_mail( 'test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
```

Comment: If you read carefully, you will see that this is not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer in your particular case does not involve the bug that is mentioned in the linked thread. There is no need to set *custom headers* to achieve what you state you want to do.

Instead you simply set the alternative body as text using `$phpmailer->AltBody`. This automatically sets the to content type `multipart/alternative` (not multipart/mixed) and you allow the `phpmailer` class to take care of the rest *without* needing to set custom headers manually.

```
add_action('phpmailer_init','wp_mail_set_text_body');
function wp_mail_set_text_body($phpmailer) {
     $phpmailer->AltBody = strip_tags($phpmailer->Body);
}

$to = 'me@example.com';
$headers = array();
$attachments = array(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.txt');
wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$attachments);
```

If you add attachments, the overall content type will automatically become `multipart/mixed` with `multipart/alternative` inside of that wchi contains `text/plain` and `text/html` parts, then followed by the attachments.

You can also add `multipart/related` (inline) attachments such as images by passing them to `wp_mail` via `$attachements` (with the 5th parameter as 'inline') - or even declaring them within the HTML body itself. These will not be accessible to the text version as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the [link you posted](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/):

> The default content type is ‘text/plain’ which does not allow using HTML. However, you can set the content type of the email by using the 'wp_mail_content_type’ filter.

Adding this to functions.php, as stated in [wp_mail_content_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type):

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Not what I was asking.