# wp_mail() headers multipart/alternative

Tags: plugin-development, email, wp-mail

I am trying to send email via `wp_mail()` containing both plain text, as well as HTML body.

When I am setting up headers like this:

```
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
  //$headers .= "From: Dawid Adach\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: d.adach@mdbootstrap.com \r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";

  //$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
```

and later on content:

```
  //Plain text body
  $message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email, the text/plain version.
  \n\nRegards,\nYour Name";
  $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

  //Html body
  $message .= '
<!--my html comes here -->
    </div>
    ';
  $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";
```

It doesn't work. 
The entire body is treated like a plain HTML. When I check an original message I can see that new line chars aren't interpreted correctly.

```
Reply-To: d.adach@mdbootstrap.com X-Mailer:PHP/7.0.8Content-Type:
 multipart/alternative@720plan.ovh.net; ,
 boundary=np57c40a2fee02f@720plan.ovh.net
```

Second thing is that when I try to set header "From: " `wp_mail` returns 0 and doesn't send anything.

I was going trough [Sending multipart (text/html) emails via wp_mail() will likely get your domain banned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191923/sending-multipart-text-html-emails-via-wp-mail-will-likely-get-your-domain-b) , however I cannot overwrite wp_mail function so I have to use original one.

Comment: "_I cannot overwrite wp_mail_" why ? explain the special configuration you have if you need help

Comment: In order to overwrite wp_mail have to put it inside mu-plugin (i.e. "wp-content/mu-plugins/functions.php" ) , as far as I understand I can do it with my local copy, however if I want to provide other users with plugin I cannot overwrite wp_mail. When I am trying to do this from my plugin I am getting error - cannot redeclare wp_mail().

Comment: you can do it in a plugin but only directly in the main file of the plugin, before all actions

Comment: Redeclaring `wp_mail()` does **not** require an mu-plugin. You can do it in any ordinary plugin.  The only thing you have to be concerned with is if another plugin attempts to redeclare it as well, but if you format your code correctly (i.e. use `if ( ! function_exists() )...`), then you'll be fine.